# c# soap result error handling authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, soap

I'm doing a C# client calling a wsdl webservice.
I added a Service References with the given link, generating all the necessary objects.

My problem is the authentication.
I tryed with SoapUI and worked with this header:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F56DE979FFAADAB54F143496748776515">
        <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">iPHOFi2DmB/eL9K6k8NmoQ==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2015-06-22T10:04:47.765Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I set my config.app file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>            
          </security>

        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://wsb.dhl.com:443/sndpt/gblDHLExpressTrack"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit"
          contract="DHL_WS.gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit" name="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But i got an error saying:

> The content type text/html;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

in my code i managed autentication like this

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"p@assword";
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you use Fiddler to examine the HTTPS traffic that your application exchanges with the web server. I assume the web server is returning an error message in plain HTML format when your web service client expects a response in some other encoding format.

Answer (score 1):

I solved! it was basically an authentication problem.

I changed my configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">            
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://wsb.dhl.com:443/sndpt/gblDHLExpressTrack"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit"
    contract="DHL_WS.gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit" name="gblDHLExpressTrackSandpit1" >
    <headers>
      <HeaderName>Value</HeaderName>
    </headers>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

And forced to don't include timestamp.

```
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingElementCollection elements = client.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
        elements.Find<System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
        client.Endpoint.Binding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(elements);
```

Of course i passed the client credentials.

Hope it helps someone :)